# Azure Cosmos MongoDB API with Azure Managed Identities

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I have an App Service in Azure connects to Azure Cosmos Mongo API using Connection String.
I am wondering if there is a way to use Managed Identity to connect to Mongo API instead of using Connection String.
I know that it is doable for Cosmos SQL API, but couldn't find any info regarding the Mongo API.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The [intended pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/managed-identity-based-authentication) is to grant access to retrieve the keys via Managed Identity, and then the application uses that access to obtain the keys and connect via normal means. You'd need to come up with your own pattern to detect recycling of primary/secondary keys and switch accordingly.

The **DocumentDB Account Contributor** role provides access to the read/write keys via the [List Keys API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db-resource-provider/2021-04-01-preview/database-accounts/list-keys)

The **Cosmos DB Account Reader Role** role provides access to the read only keys via the [List Read Only Keys API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db-resource-provider/2021-04-01-preview/database-accounts/list-read-only-keys)

Answer (score 0):

The solution for SQL API, described at [Use system-assigned managed identities to access Azure Cosmos DB data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/managed-identity-based-authentication) can also be applied to the MongoDB API via querying the *Access Key*. The code for a Node Function App would need the packages `@azure/identity`, `@azure/arm-cosmosdb` and `mongodb`.

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';
import { ManagedIdentityCredential } from '@azure/identity';
import { CosmosDBManagementClient } from '@azure/arm-cosmosdb';

async function initializeClient(): Promise<MongoClient> {
  const subscriptionId = ...;
  const resourceGroupName = ...;
  const cosmosDbUrl = ...;
  const accountName = ...;

  const armClient = new CosmosDBManagementClient(
    new ManagedIdentityCredential(), subscriptionId
  );
  const { primaryMasterKey } = await armClient.databaseAccounts.listKeys(
    resourceGroupName, accountName
  );
  return MongoClient.connect(
    cosmosDbUrl,
    { auth: { username: accountName, password: primaryMasterKey } }
  );
}
```

The Managed Identity of the Function App requires the permission `Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/listKeys/action`. Therefore you can assign the role [DocumentDB Account Contributor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#documentdb-account-contributor) to the Managed Identity. See also [Azure role-based access control in Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/role-based-access-control).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the [Azure.ResourceManager.CosmosDB](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.ResourceManager.CosmosDB/) package, you can retrieve  the keys using this code:

```
ArmClient armClient = new ArmClient(new ManagedIdentityCredential(clientId: managedIdentityClientId));
CosmosDBAccountResource accountResource = armClient.GetCosmosDBAccountResource(new ResourceIdentifier("/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<resource-group>/providers/Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/<cosmos-db-account>"));
CosmosDBAccountKeyList keys = accountResource.GetKeys().Value;
string primaryMasterKey = keys.PrimaryMasterKey;
```