# Wait for the promise

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure, asynchronous, promise

I'm trying to use the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70946169/azure-cosmos-mongodb-api-with-azure-managed-identities) answer to extend one OSS application.

However app.js is sync and no matter what I do, I cant force it to wait for the promise to resolve.

app.js

```
var cosmos = require('./cosmos.js');
const key = cosmos.key(var1, var2, var3);
console.log(key); // << shows Promise { <pending> }

mongoose.connect(`redacted`, {
  auth: {
    username: config.database.name,
    password: key
  }
});
```

cosmos.js

```
async function retriveKey(subId, resGrp, server) {
    const { EnvironmentCredential } = require("@azure/identity");
    const { CosmosDBManagementClient } = require("@azure/arm-cosmosdb");
    const armClient = new CosmosDBManagementClient(
        new EnvironmentCredential(), subId
    );

    const { primaryMasterKey } = await armClient.databaseAccounts.listKeys(
        resGrp, server
    );
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(primaryMasterKey), 1000);
    });
}

exports.key = retriveKey
```

If i console.log() inside the async function it actually shows the key, however mongoose db connection doesn't wait for the promise to get resolved, it starts connecting straight away and fails with something like: `password must be a string`.

If i hardcode actual key instead of this promise - everything works fine.

EDIT:

halfway there:

```
// pull cosmos keys
async function retriveKey(subId, resGrp, server) {
    const { EnvironmentCredential } = require("@azure/identity");
    const { CosmosDBManagementClient } = require("@azure/arm-cosmosdb");
    const armClient = new CosmosDBManagementClient(
        new EnvironmentCredential(), subId
    );
    const { primaryMasterKey } = await armClient.databaseAccounts.listKeys(
        resGrp, server
    );
    return primaryMasterKey // don't even need a promise here
}

exports.key = retriveKey
```

```
var mongooseConnected; // global variable
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  if (!moongooseConnected) {
    moongooseConnected = cosmos.key(var1, var2, var3).then(function (key) {
      mongoose.connect(`xxx`,
        {
          auth: {
            username: config.database.name,
            password: key
          }
        }
      );
      console.log(key); // works as expected

      require('./models/user');
      require('./models/audit');

      require('./routes/user')(app);
      require('./routes/audit')(app, io);
    });
  }
  moongooseConnected.then(function () {
    next();
  });
});
```

the database connection gets established, `console.log(key)` shows proper key in the log, however no routes are present in the app.

if i move routes or models outside of this app.use(xyz) - i'm starting to see failures due to:

> Connection 0 was disconnected when calling `createCollection`

or

> MongooseError [MissingSchemaError]: Schema hasn't been registered for model "User".

which (i assume) means they require mongoose to be instantiated, but they are not waiting.

Comment: Not directly related to your question but you never resolve the promise in `comsos.js` so it will wait forever

Comment: well, it definitely doesn't wait at all :)

Comment: You never wait for the promise. However, if you did you would wait forever since the promise never resolves

Comment: okay, care to tell me how to fix that?

Comment: Not sure what `listKeys` returns but if that's the value you want you can do`setTimeout(()=>resolve(armClient.data...)`

Comment: use promise.then when you want to return data, after the operation is complete

Comment: i tried doing like this: `key.then(resp => resp)` however it didn't work

Comment: @mousetail - tried doing that and it didn't really change anything :( updated my code. i also tried adding then in app.js, but I'm getting all sorts of weird errors

Comment: Have you tried, in `app.js` to add `key.then((key)=>mongoose.connect(...)`

Comment: yeah, i tried doing that, but i think that other parts of app.js start crushing, ie parts that require db connection don't wait for the `key.then((key)=>mongoose.connect(...))` to finish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you switch from CommonJS modules to [ES modules](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/esm.html), you can use `await` to wait for a promise to resolve:

```js
import cosmos from './cosmos.js';
const key = await cosmos.key(var1, var2, var3);
console.log(key);
await mongoose.connect(`redacted`, {
  auth: {
    username: config.database.name,
    password: key
  }
});
```

Alternatively, you can wait with the initialization of `mongoose` until the first request comes in, because express middleware is asynchronous:

```js
var mongooseConnected; // global variable
function connectMongoose() {
  if (!mongooseConnected)
    mongooseConnected = cosmos.key(var1, var2, var3)
    .then(key => mongoose.connect(`redacted`, {
      auth: {
        username: config.database.name,
        password: key
      }
    }));
  return mongooseConnected;
}
module.exports = connectMongoose;
```

If the code above is needed elsewhere, it can be put in a separate module and imported wherever needed:

```js
const connectMongoose = require("./connectMongoose");
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  connectMongoose().then(function() {
    next();
  });
});
require('./routes/user')(app);
require('./routes/audit')(app, io);
```

Note that if several parallel requests come in, only the first of these will let the global variable `mongooseConnected` equal a promise, and all these requests will wait for it to resolve before calling `next()`.

Also note that additional routes of `app` must be registered *after* this `app.use` command, not inside it.

Comment: See my augmented answer.

Comment: yes, its express. your code works, however it appears i either need another solution or another question. for your code to work i had to move routes code to inside the `if` and it appears routes never get populated. i had to do that, because route implementation appear to depend on the schema that is created after mongoose connection is established :(

Comment: Don't understand, can you share some more code in the question?

Comment: here you go, thanks!

Comment: no :( because code inside those files is trying to use mongoose and exceptions mentioned in the question are raised ;(

Comment: I have edited my answer again, because `mongoose.connect` is also asynchronous and must be `awaited`.

Comment: this is for the `es modules`, right? i don't think i can do that, i'd need to replace `require()` with import everywhere and probably risk breaking something else? for your other answer those same imports from routes and models are not waiting for the connection to go through :( can we chat, perhaps?

Comment: I changed the `.then(...)` line in my answer for Common JS. Compare the code in my answer with the code in your question.

Comment: yeah, i noticed that, but it doesn't help, because those `require()` models and routes files are not inside `then()` so they get imported\executed way before mongoose is instantiated, hence everything breaks :(

Comment: Then please share the code of your `./routes/user` and `./routes/audit`.

Comment: https://github.com/pwndoc/pwndoc/tree/master/backend/src - this is the code, basically. This solution obviously works as-is, but I'd really like to add dynamic connection string fetch into the solution, i could never imagine it would be so hard with all this sync\async stuff :( for the replacement part, do i need to do something like this:
`app.locals.mongooseConnected.then(app.get(xxx))`? this is a bit confusing

Comment: I have made one more (final, I hope) edit to my answer that explains how the "mongoose connection promise" can be turned into a reusable module.

Comment: take a look at my answer and many thanks for pointing me in the right direction. i tried doing it your way, but it didn't work, perhaps I did something wrong or misunderstood you.

Answer (score 0):

unless somebody comes up with a way to do this with less changes to the original code base, this is what I'm using:

cosmos.js

```
// pull cosmos keys
async function retriveKey(subId, resGrp, server) {
    const { DefaultAzureCredential } = require("@azure/identity");
    const { CosmosDBManagementClient } = require("@azure/arm-cosmosdb");
    const armClient = new CosmosDBManagementClient(
        new DefaultAzureCredential(), subId
    );
    const { primaryMasterKey } = await armClient.databaseAccounts.listKeys(
        resGrp, server
    );
    return primaryMasterKey
}

exports.key = retriveKey
```

app.js

```
// pull cosmos keys
var cosmos = require('./cosmos');
let key = cosmos.key(var1, var2, var3)
mongoose.connect(
  `xxx`,
  {
    auth: {
      username: config.database.name,
      password: key
    }
  }
).catch(
  err => {
    console.log("dOrty h4ck");
    key.then(k => mongoose.connect(
      `xxx`,
      {
        auth: {
          username: config.database.name,
          password: k
        }
      }
    )
    );
  }
)
```

basically, like Heiko mentioned, `mongoose.connect()` is actually async, but somehow blocking (??). so while first `mongoose.connect()` always fails - it gives enough time for the code to retrieve the key, then I catch the error and connect again. no other changes to the [original code base](https://github.com/pwndoc/pwndoc/tree/master/backend/src) are needed.