# Why does "app.use(express.static(__dirname));" break this program

Tags: node.js, express, static

So, I'm trying to write a program that pulls items from a database that records the title, release dates, ratings, and choice images for certain videogames.  This seems to work fine, except when I include the  "app.use(express.static(__dirname));" line.  Then this causes an error, not one that's visible in the terminal that runs the node code, but in the Developer's Console on index.html.  That error reads "GET http://localhost:3000/fill 404 (Not Found)".  I don't get this error when that line is commented out.  What's going on?

Here's the server code:

```
//so, let's outline the goals of this project.  There are two sections
//1) Pictures, titles, and links to reviews
//2) A list of games with titles, release date, rating, and I guess links to reviews.

const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const path = require("path");
const mysql = require("mysql");
// const request = require("request");

const app = express();

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("App listening on PORT 3000");
});

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "game_site_db"
})

// app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
// app.use(bodyParser.json());

//why does this break the program?
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

var gamesArray = [];

app.get("/", function(req, res)
{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "index.html"))

    //function fill creates an array from the database which can be used to 'fill' the index page
fill();

    function fill(){

        //this empties the game array to prevent data build up.  I think there's a more elegant
        //solution (terminating the connection) but I'll look into that later
        gamesArray = [];

        connection.query("SELECT * from games ORDER BY rel DESC;", function(err, result){
            if (err) throw err;
            
            let i;
                //  console.log("result:")
                // console.log(result);
                //this shows result is an array with 8 objects, now why on earth
                //does pushing each item from this array multiply it by 8?

                console.log("result length:")
                console.log(result.length);
                //result.length is 8.  So why oh why does push each individual item of the array
                //into games array...ugh

             for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) { 
  gamesArray.push(result[i]);



}


console.log("Games Array:")
console.log(gamesArray);

app.get("/fill", function(req, res) {
  return res.json(gamesArray);
});

        })
    }
})
```

And here's the index script code:

```
<script>
            function fill(){
            $.get("/fill", function(data) {
                    console.log(data);

                    //why on Earth does the former work, but not this, even
                    //when I plug in gibberish?
                    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                    {
                            $("#side").append("<tr><td>" + data[i].title + "<br><br>" + data[i].rel.substring(0,10) + "</td><td><span class='rating'>" + data[i].rating + "</span></td></tr>")
                    }

                    
                    
            })
        }
        </script>
```

Comment: It is hard to see because of the indentation, but your code contains one `app.get(...)` inside another, which does not make sense. `app.get` statements are used to register a `function(req, res)` that handles a certain request, and all these registrations must be executed _before_ any request is actually handled. Read the [middleware documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html).

Comment: Hmmm yeah IIRC I just copied and pasted that.  But it served its purpose when I used it an another project.

Comment: Expressjs.com is where I found that, it says "For example, use the following code to serve images, CSS files, and JavaScript files in a directory named public:

app.use(express.static('public'))"

Comment: It actually works when I make a directory called "public" and use that, but why can't it work with __dirname, I wonder?  Another program of mine did.

Comment: Your function `fill` serves only to fill the `gamesArray` _once_, right? Since this is an asynchronous operation, you cannot simply invoke it in a top-level statement in your server-side code. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73048205/wait-for-the-promise for how to deal with this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wait for the promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73048205/wait-for-the-promise)