# How can I use supertest lib using the same app instance in expressjs

Tags: node.js, supertest, superagent

I have the below code in my app.ts file. How can I export the app instance so that I can use it with superagent lib for my tests?

```
const port = 8080; 
const host = "0.0.0.0"; 
const init = async () => { 
    const app = express(); 
    const middlewareA = await middlewareA();
    app.use([middlewareA]); 
    app.use(routes); 
    app.listen(port, host, () => { 
        console.log(Working server on ${host}:${port}); 
    }); 
}; 
init();
```

Comment: Return it from the inside of the function?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot export the `app` asynchronously, but you can export the asynchronous `init` function and let it resolve to the `app` once it has started listening:

```js
async function init() {
  const app = express(); 
  const middlewareA = await middlewareA();
  app.use([middlewareA]); 
  app.use(routes); 
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    app.listen(port, host, () => { 
      console.log(Working server on ${host}:${port});
      resolve(app);
    });
  }); 
};
```

followed by `module.exports = init;` for Common JS modules or by `export default init;` for ES modules.

In order to use the `init()` function, you can then either import it and await its result in an ES module, or you can defer the `init` until the first request comes in that needs it. Both options are explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73048972/16462950).